# YML syntax: How do I get the same commands to run before each stage without repeating myself in the YML file?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, pipeline, cicd

I've set up a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file as follows for my self-hosted runner.

```
stages:
  - set-environment
  - check-code

set-environment:
  stage: set-environment
  script:
    - C:\Users\9279\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
    - conda activate temp

run_tests:
  stage: check-code
  script:
    - pytest test.py

type_checker:
  stage: check-code
  script:
    - (ls -recurse *.py).fullname | foreach-object {echo "`n$_`n";mypy --strict $_}
```

I intended to use the `set-environment` stage to make `mypy` and `pytest` available to the subsequent `check-code` stage. Unfortunately, that's not how it works. GitLab destroys the shell after each stage completes.

I know this is a flaw in my understanding of how the Gitlab Runner works. How can I have the commands in `set-environment` run before `run_tests` and `type_checker` without repeating them in the YML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a gitlab-ci.yaml you can define a global `before_script`. It would look something like this.

```
stages:
  - check-code

before_script:
  - C:\Users\9279\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
  - conda activate temp

run_tests:
  stage: check-code
  script:
    - pytest test.py

type_checker:
  stage: check-code
  script:
    - (ls -recurse *.py).fullname | foreach-object {echo "`n$_`n";mypy --strict $_}
```

I would highly recommend you to read the [gitlab-ci.yaml documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/). As there are way more nice functions like this.